# How to use Firebase Analytics in some other class which is not an Activity class in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase-analytics

We know that, we can log event in an activity using the code:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("hello", new Bundle());
```

Suppose I have this class "Student", which is a simple class called inside different activities. All I want to know is how to use FirebaseAnalytics inside this "Student" class without passing the context or getApplicationContext() or "this" keyword?

N.B: FirebaseCrashlytics can be used in "Student" class as follow:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("logstudentclass");
```

Also "Student" class be like:

```
public class Student{
     private String name;
     private String roll;
      
     public Student(String name, String, roll){
         this.name=name;
         this.roll=roll;
     }
     // bla bla bla methods
     // bla bla bla getters setters
}
```

Comment: Hi, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361/2649154 to see how you can get application context outside of Activity/Fragment.

Comment: In that case, I need to declare a function to get the Application Context for every Activity class. Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class, extending Application class:

Create a file MyApplication.java with the following code:

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static Application context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

This class extends the Application class and lives throughout the entire lifetime of the application. Using a static variable for storing the Application value (your Context), and a static method to get it, makes it approachable from anywhere in your code.

in your AndroidManifest.xml - state that you want to use MyApplication class as your application class:

```
<application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyApplication">

    ...
</application>
```

Wherever you want to get the application Context, use:

```
MyApplication.getAppContext()
```

In Your case:

```
FirebaseAnalytics
    .getInstance(MyApplication.getAppContext())
    .logEvent("hello", new Bundle());
```

More about Application class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application).

Note that there are downsides for this approach, for instance, trying to use the context before it was initialized, string translations, and more so use it carefully.

Comment: Suppose, I don't know in which Activity my class is used. In that case, what should I do to get the Application context? Should I build a common getContext() function in every Activity class?

Comment: You use MyApplication.getAppContext() from where you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a public static reference to FirebaseAnalytics in your Application class

```
   public class MyApp extends Application {
    public static  FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;
    @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    }
   }
```

Next, you add the same name to your Android Manifest file, in the Application tag:

```
<application
  android:name=".MyApp"
  ...
```

Now you can use it inside `Student` like:

```
MyApp.firebaseAnalytics.log("logsstudentclass")
```